# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Not a valid Win32 FileTime

Tags: adfs

I am trying to implement ADFS authentication in my ASP.net Web Application. I have configured my web application to use the adfs authentication and also set up the relying party trust in adfs. When I browse my web application, browser is redirected to the adfs login page. After the submitting the login details, it shows the error page from adfs. I don't have much knowledge about ADFS.
Error logged by adfs is below:

```
    Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for details. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Not a valid Win32 FileTime.
Parameter name: fileTime
   at System.DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(Int64 fileTime)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetPasswordExpiryDetails(SafeLsaReturnBufferHandle profileHandle, DateTime& nextPasswordChange, DateTime& lastPasswordChange)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetLsaLogonUserInfo(SafeHGlobalHandle pLogonInfo, Int32 logonInfoSize, DateTime& nextPasswordChange, DateTime& lastPasswordChange, String authenticationType, String issuerName)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetLsaLogonUser(UserNameSecurityToken token, DateTime& nextPasswordChange, DateTime& lastPasswordChange, String issuerName)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.MSISWindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenInternal(SecurityToken token)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.MSISWindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.WSTrust.SecurityTokenServiceManager.GetEffectivePrincipal(SecurityTokenElement securityTokenElement, SecurityTokenHandlerCollection securityTokenHandlerCollection)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.WSTrust.SecurityTokenServiceManager.Issue(RequestSecurityToken request, IList`1& identityClaimSet)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken request, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(MSISRequestSecurityToken signInRequest, Uri& replyTo, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestSingleSingOnToken(ProtocolContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSsoSecurityToken(WSFederationSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken, SecurityToken& ssoSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(WSFederationSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponse(WSFederationSignInContext federationPassiveContext, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponse(WSFederationSignInContext federationPassiveContext, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

Please help.

Comment: I was using Microsoft Edge browser to browse my web application. In Google Chrome and Internet Explorer Web application is working fine without any issue. So I think that Edge is posting incorrect data while submitting authentication details.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the AD FS Setup did not initialize the following GPO value correctly and the default of *unspecified* is not working.

The missing value prevents ADFS from securely communicating with Active Directory. The strange thing is that some ADFS calls succeeded. The latest Microsoft.Owin Katana packages did fail as described above on my server without this setting.

Network security: Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos
under
GPO_name\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options

1. Start - Run - mmc.exe
2. File - Add Snap in for Local Computer Policy
3. Navigate to the above path
4. select all available options.

[image]
The following article helped me resolve this issue:
[Network security: Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852180%28v=ws.11%29.aspx)

Selecting all Encryption types then rebooting the AD FS Server resolved this issue for me.